Issue with Uploading Multiple Files to S3 Storage as one single file
I am attempting to upload multiple distinct files as parts of a single file in S3 storage. The final file, which is supposed to be the fused version of all the uploaded files, is generated and shows the correct size. However, only a portion of the first page of the first file is stored, and the rest of the data appears to be lost.
Could you help me understand why this is happening?
PS : Merge all files into one before uploading them part by part as a single file is not an option for me
Here is my code:
    import os
    import math
    import boto3
    
    def upload_to_ovh_part_files(bucket, parts_folder):
        """
        Fonction pour uploader des fichiers en morceaux sur OVH Object Storage.
        
        :param bucket: Le nom du bucket sur OVH
        :param parts_folder: Le chemin du dossier contenant les parties à uploader
        """
    
        
        s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            aws_access_key_id='my_key',
            aws_secret_access_key='my-sak',
            endpoint_url='https:...',
            
        )
    
        
        parts = []
        upload_id = None
    
        
        docx_files = [f for f in os.listdir(parts_folder) if f.endswith('.docx')]
        print(f'Found {len(docx_files)} parts to upload.')
    
        
        if docx_files:
            mp = s3.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket, Key='rapport_final.docx')
            upload_id = mp['UploadId']
    
            try:
                for i, docx_file in enumerate(docx_files, start=1):
                    print(f'upload de {i} file ')
                    file_path = os.path.join(parts_folder, docx_file)
                    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
                    print(f'Uploading part {i}: {docx_file} (size: {file_size / (1024 * 1024):.2f} MB)')
    
                    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                        data = f.read()
                        part = s3.upload_part(
                            Bucket=bucket,
                            Key='rapport_final.docx',
                            PartNumber=i,
                            UploadId=upload_id,
                            Body=data
                        )
                        parts.append({
                            'ETag': part['ETag'],
                            'PartNumber': i
                        })
    
                
                s3.complete_multipart_upload(
                    Bucket=bucket,
                    Key='rapport_final.docx',
                    UploadId=upload_id,
                    MultipartUpload={'Parts': parts}
                )
                print("Upload completed successfully!")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error during upload: {e}")
                if upload_id:
                    s3.abort_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket, Key='rapport_final.docx', UploadId=upload_id)
        else:
            print("No DOCX files found to upload.")

parts_folder = "rapports"
bucket_name = "mon-bucket-rapport"

upload_to_ovh_part_files(bucket_name, parts_folder)


Will this work for just a single file?

Yes as long as its size is bigger than 5mb

The documentation says Body=b'bytes'|file,, so you might try removing data = f.read() and then use Body=f.

By the way, a .docx file is a zip file, so concatenating several files into a docx file probably doesn't make sense. What is the content of the source files?
